# Gtk non blocking calls solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

Hello guys Iam writing Gtk+ GUI  application in python which plays video and moves camera using onvif Iam using async calls for SOAP service within application.But what happens is that when I press one of the button for moving camera video hangs for a second then it's ok while button is pressed but  when it's released it hangs again .

## Onvif continuous move class

```
class ContinuousMove(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,onvif_service):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
        self.onvif_service=onvif_service
        self.position=self.onvif_service.get_client().factory.create('ns4:PTZVector')
        self.profileToken=self.onvif_service.get_client().factory.create('ns4:ReferenceToken')
        self.speed=self.onvif_service.get_client().factory.create('ns4:PTZSpeed')
        self.timeout=self.onvif_service.get_client().factory.create('ns4:Timeout')
        self.executor=concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)


    def move(self,x,y,zoom):
        future = self.executor.submit(self.__move__,x,y,zoom)
    def __move__(self,x,y,zoom):

       self.position.PanTilt._x=x
       self.position.PanTilt._y=y
       self.position.Zoom._x=zoom

       self.profileToken='media_profile1'

       self.onvif_service.get_client().service.ContinuousMove(self.profileToken,self.position)
```

As you see here I used conncurent.future module and their class ThreadPoolExecutor for async call

Next I create instance of ContinuousMove class in player class which extends Gtk.Window
and then I create buttons and set event callbacks.

```
    class player(Gtk.Window):
        #bunch of functions
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self):
        self.gui_init()
        self.camera=ContinuousMove(onvif_service)
        self.player=Player(self.previewArea)#class which constructs gstreamer pipeline and renders it on previewArea

    def gui_init(self):
        self.previewArea=Gtk.RenderArea()
        self.buttonDown=Gtk.Button("DOWN")
        self.buttonDown.connect("pressed",self.on_down_pressed)
    
    def on_down_pressed(self,btn):
    #instance of ContinuousMove
        self.Camera.move(0,-0.1,0)

app=player()
app.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I would be grateful if you could point me what am I doing wrong here and why video hangs.

## PS:

Didn't pasted whole code because it's gigantic I hope you'll understand the problem from this.

## EDIT:

I added init of my Player object and RenderArea object because I think it's relevant for this problem.
I init Player object and send it RenderArea so it can render video to it.
Now question is could button widget block RenderArea widget in some way ?

I'll explain details what happens.For example when I press DOWN button it freezes video for the second it looks like it skips a few frames.Tried almost everything and nothing seems to work.The problem is not RenderArea nor Gstreamer problem is move method and/or button pressed  event.

Comment: How `self.Camera` is set? When `ContinuousMove()` thread is started?

Comment: To avoid further hunting, create [a minimal complete code example that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): make the code runnable as is, remove all unrelated code (if the issue is still present if you remove the code then it is unrelated), replace blocking calls with stubs (e.g., `time.sleep(10)` instead of making network requests or use `time.sleep(1)` and print a `time.time()` value instead of playing a video), etc.

Comment: For the first question check edit above.I'll try it ,this problem is bothering me for couple of days it's not that big but I want smooth video playback in every moment.I found application called Winpdb for debuging but the problem is that it's for python 2.7. I would like to know is there any good debuging tool for python3 so I can track down what happens when I press button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_down_pressed()` looks like an event handler. If it blocks then the GUI "freezes" (doesn't respond).

`with`-statement calls `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` on exit that blocks the method.
To avoid blocking in `Camera.move()` method, move the creation of `ThreadPoolExecutor()` to `__init__()` and call only `executor.submit()` that doesn't block there.

Comment: Tried that but still hangs when I try to move camera.See edit for more info

Comment: @user3820641: `move(self,x,y,zoom)` method is still blocking in your code.

Comment: Sorry bro this was not related to my application it's some kind of onvif bug when I call ContinuousMove